# Update Cart items price at Checkout

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to update cart item price through the code below, 'sales_flat_order_item' table show change in price when my code is execute but once i go to next step or reload the page then all item prices change back to its previous values.
This is my code using through `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` event/observer

```
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $u_item){
          $u_item->setPrice(100);
          $u_item->setCustomPrice(100);
          $u_item->save();
}
```

i had also tried to update `sales_flat_order_item` row values with direct sql but it also reverted back once i go to next step. i am using Magento EE, any idea what i am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your discounts don't stick around is when Magento calls collect totals on the quote it repopulates the original price overwriting any customizations.

You need to apply the discount to the `sales_flat_quote` where it will remain and be used in `sales_flat_order` which is a reflection of the cart once quote is converted into an order ( actually copied over ).

> The event you want to hook into is:

```
sales_quote_collect_totals_after
```

Something along the lines of:

```
   $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
   $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
```

That being said, using shopping cart price rules is the convention here to use the built-in admin panel UI functionality.

If you're looking for adding additional discounts functionality you can always programmatically creaate a one time coupon, apply it to the cart and delete it thereafter for fine-grain control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i cannot do this with discount.